# Hololens 2 / MRTK / Unity / Asking for permissions programmatically

Tags: unity-game-engine, permissions, hololens, mrtk

Is it possible to check if app has permissions and if don't ask for permissions programmatically on Hololens 2?

In manifest permissions are already declared by sometimes if you miss the permission popup or click on NO by mistake the app doesn't ask for permission never again.

Unity 2020.3.13f1

MRTK 2.7.3

**- Update -**

I asked for this feature here:

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/10675

Please support the request!

Comment: Could you please share more details about which permissions you want to check? It should be possible to check the permissions with code, but it's impossible to ask for permissions programmatically.

Comment: @JayZuo I need to check Mic and Camera permissions. 
I asked for this feature on MRTK-Unity GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

To check Microphone and Camera permissions on HoloLens 2, we can take advantage of WinRT API [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture). If the app does not have Microphone and Camera permissions, when calling the [`InitializeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.initializeasync#windows-media-capture-mediacapture-initializeasync) method, it will throw a `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

If we got this exception, there is no way to re-ask for permission programmatically. We should let the user to grant us the required permissions again in **Settings** with using the [`ms-settings:appsfeatures-app`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#apps) URI, which can open the advanced settings page for our app.

```cs
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
using (MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture())
    try
    {
        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();       
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:appsfeatures-app"));
    }
#endif
```

Another way to check the permissions would be using [AppCapability Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authorization.appcapabilityaccess.appcapability). [`CheckAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authorization.appcapabilityaccess.appcapability.checkaccess) method will return the access status. If the status is `DeniedByUser`, we will still need to open the advanced settings page for our app using the `ms-settings:appsfeatures-app` URI and let the user to grant us the required permissions.

Comment: I have a problem: in my UWP app I can't import Windows namespace.

Comment: Since you are using Unity, please refer to [Universal Windows Platform: WinRT API in C# scripts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-scripts.html). When you double-click a script in the Unity editor, it will by default launch your script in an editor project. The WinRT APIs will appear to be unknown because the Visual Studio project doesn't reference the Windows Runtime. The ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT directive is undefined and any #if wrapped code is ignored until you build your project into a UWP Visual Studio solution.